# Additive functors preserve projective objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $F:\mathscr{A}\rightarrow\mathscr{B}$ be an additive functor between abelian categories. Let $P\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{A})$ be a projective object.

I believe that $FP\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{B})$ doesn't remain projective in general. I'm looking for a concrete counterexample that I failed to construct.

Moreover, does there exist any sufficient condition which makes an additive functor preserve projective objects?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? The most basic additive functors would be $Hom(A,\bullet)$ and $A\otimes \bullet$ in categories of modules, and they don't preserve projectives.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I stupidly ignored these very basic functors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sufficient condition: if $F$ is the left adjoint of an exact functor, then $F$ preserves projective objects. This is not limited to additive functors between abelian categories: if $F$ is the left adjoint of a functor (between general categories) that preserves epimorphisms, then $F$ preserves projective objects.